# Everytime old image display after uploading new image in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have a issue regarding image uploading. I'm using cakephp framework and jquery to upload profile image.

I have created a form in jquery popup box and everything works fine but after uploading image, when I reopened popbox everytime it display old image.

If anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue, please answer because I stuck at this point.

Following is my code to upload image:

```
<div style="min-width:450px !important;">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Admin',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'admins','action'=>'profileImage'),'enctype'=>"multipart/form-data") );?>
<table class="withPanel">
    <tr>
        <td class="rightPanel">
            <div class="box round popup">
                <div class="heading_content">
                    <h1>Change My Profile Image</h1>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div>          
                <div class="field">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => 'Upload Image')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <div style="float: left;height: 250px;padding-top: 25px;width: 250px;">
                        <?php 
                            if($profile_image != '') {
                                echo $this->Html->image('adminphoto/'.$profile_image, array('style' => 'max-width:250px; max-height:250px;', 'alt' => 'Profile image'));
                            } else {
                                echo $this->Html->image('admin/na.png', array('alt' => 'No Image' ));
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttonContainer" style='text-align:right'>
                    <input class="btn  btn-success" type="submit" value="Save">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#AdminAdminProfileImageForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType:  'json', 
        beforeSubmit: function () { 
            showloader("Please wait...");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            hideloader();
            shownotification(response.message,response.status);
        }
    });
});
```

thanks.

Comment: Please share your code as well!!

Comment: use jquery `success` function to show new image ,as after uploading iamge page is not reloading, it won't change data stored in variable. So either reload page after save or use `success` function of jquery where u can return data from your controller action

Comment: This form is loaded in popup by calling ajax, so every time when I reopen it, the value of $profile_image is comes from database